# Opencart: How to include a script on certain pages?

Tags: php, opencart

I'd like to include a script to detect `$_GET` values on certain pages of the site. If I use the script in `header.tpl`, it will add the script on all pages. If I use it as a template file and display it as `Layout` in the Extensions > Modules, it gets added to all the pages within that Layout. Is there a way to include this only on certain selected pages? I'm sure this will have to done programatically. Just wanted to find out if there is an elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the `$_GET` files using the correct method of `$this->request->get` in any of the controller, model or view files. As for an elegant solution, that really depends on *which* pages you want it to show on and also what region of the page. For example, if you only want to use code on the product pages, but want to have the code placed in the header, you would need to check for the route to be `product/product` in your `header.php` controller in the `index()` method, then pass the data to the template using `$this->data['your-variable'] = $some_data;`. Similarly, this would be almost the same on a product page using the `product.php` controller and skipping the route check since that controller will only be called on product pages

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What if I want to access `$_GET` or include some other script only on a few particular product pages?

Comment: You would need to check the `product_id` key in `$this->request->get` against your list of allowed/wanted product ID values - note that `$this->request->get` and `$_GET` are the same, however OpenCart can and usually does change values in `$this->request->get` after the page load for things like the `route` key value when using SEO keywords, therefore its advisable to use that instead of `$_GET` instead of `$_GET`. It also has the values cleaned to prevent any malicious values. You may want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13484904/711273 if you're not too adept in OpenCart's MVC