# How to use Page Id in Opencart

Tags: php, templates, opencart

How can I use the id of a page in a Opencart template to show content only for that specific page? Or something similar?

Thanks so much
Mark

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you provide an example and further clarification? You can create information pages for your site content.

Comment: I would like to insert code from the template file but only for a certain page, very similary to the following `<?php if (isset($category_id) && $category_id == '65') { ?>
                per month
          <?php }  ?>` Also this example only works for products within a category not a category page itself

Comment: @Unknowndady, which template exactly you want to change? If it is category template (product/category.tpl), and you want to do some hard coding inside template - you can use $heading_title variable (it is the name of category). Id is stored in &path var...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Product.tpl**

```
product_id
```

**For Category.tpl**

```
path
```

**For Content.tpl**

```
information_id
```

Edit those .tpl files and use the variables I have stated. You can use in practice in the .tpl files like:

```
<?
if(isset($_GET["product_id"])==""){
 // yes
} else {
 // do something else   
}
?>
```

For security. You can use [mysql_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php);

You can also use the library in certain instances. Example in Content.tpl which I believe is the issue you want. I recommend against changes like this. Make modules or better logic.

Also, $_GET can be replaced.

Note that `$this->request->get` and `$_GET` are the same, however OpenCart can and usually does change values in `$this->request->get` after the page load for things like the route key value when using SEO keywords, therefore its advisable to use that instead of `$_GET` instead of `$_GET`. It also has the values cleaned to prevent any malicious values. (Reference Jay: [Opencart: How to include a script on certain pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974558/opencart-how-to-include-a-script-on-certain-pages#comment24519928_16974826))

Comment: Thank you so much, I couldn't get `<?
if(isset($_GET["product_id"])==""){
 // yes
} else {
 // do something else   
}
?>` to work but I did get this to `<?php if ($this->request->get['path'] == 65) { ?>
                per month
                <?php } ?>`. Thanks for leading me in the right direction!

Comment: What if I wanted to affect only one of the products on the Category.tpl ?

Comment: @Unknowndaddy you could edit inaide the for loop by doing if else command inside the foreach call.. do you see it?

Comment: Yes but how do I affect each product in that for each call differently. Say I want to type in a different price for each product.

Comment: You need to be specific about your question as here your askingtwo questions. Why would you do that. Could you not use special atattribute or something else?

Comment: I just don't know which attribute would work, I tried product_id but to no avail. I'm trying to sell a monthly service and I have the base price at $0.00 and required Available Options that are different based on the period you want the service.

Comment: Can you post another question and link it here with the FULL site scenario .. what you want to do please rather than just this comment field? Thanks